# Expression simplifier in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to write an expression simplifier in Scala which can do the following

`a + a + 1 + a +a => 2*a + 1 + 2*a`

Currently, what I have written is only able to simplify the expression from the left side.

In this case my code is able to do this
`Variable("a")+ a+ 1+ a+a => 2*a + 1 + a+ a`

Can anyone tell me how can I simplify the expression further. Here is my code

```
import dsl.Expr.{Add, Divide, Literal, Multiply, Variable, simplifier}
import dsl.main.program.simplify

sealed trait Statement

sealed trait Expr extends Statement {
  self =>
  def +(right: Expr): Expr = Expr.Add(self, right)

  def -(right: Expr): Expr = Expr.Add(self, Expr.Negative(right))

  def *(right: Expr): Expr = Expr.Multiply(self, right)

  def /(right: Expr): Expr = Expr.Divide(self, right)

  def evaluate(scope: Map[String, Expr]): Double = self match {
    case expr: Expr =>
      expr match {
        case Expr.Divide(left, right)          => left.evaluate(scope) / right.evaluate(scope)
        case Expr.Multiply(left, right)        => left.evaluate(scope) * right.evaluate(scope)
        case Expr.Add(left, right)             => left.evaluate(scope) + right.evaluate(scope)
        case Expr.Negative(expr)               => -expr.evaluate(scope)
        case Expr.Literal(value)               => value
        case Expr.Variable(name, defaultValue) => scope.getOrElse(name, defaultValue).evaluate(scope)
      }
  }

  def simplify(expr: Expr): Expr =
    expr match {
      case Divide(left, right)                  => if (left == right) Literal(1.0) else simplify(expr)
      case Multiply(left: Expr, right: Expr)    => Multiply(simplify(left), simplify(right))
      case Add(left: Variable, right: Variable) => if (left == right) Multiply(Literal(2.0), left) else expr
      case Add(left: Literal, right: Literal)   => Literal(left.evaluate(Map()) + right.evaluate(Map()))
      case Add(left: Multiply, right: Variable) =>
        left match {
          case Multiply(a: Literal, b: Variable) =>
            if (b == right) Multiply(Literal(a.evaluate(Map()) + 1), b) else expr
          case Multiply(a: Variable, b: Literal) =>
            if (a == right) Multiply(Literal(b.evaluate(Map()) + 1), a) else expr
          case _                                 => expr
        }
      case Add(left: Variable, right: Multiply) =>
        right match {
          case Multiply(a: Literal, b: Variable) => if (b == left) Multiply(Literal(a.evaluate(Map()) + 1), b) else expr
          case Multiply(a: Variable, b: Literal) => if (a == left) Multiply(Literal(b.evaluate(Map()) + 1), a) else expr
          case _                                 => expr
        }
      case Add(left: Expr, right: Expr)         => Add(simplify(left), simplify(right))
      case _                                    => expr
    }
}

object Expr {
  case class Variable(name: String, defaultValue: Expr) extends Expr
  case class Literal(value: Double)                     extends Expr
  case class Add(left: Expr, right: Expr)               extends Expr
  case class Multiply(left: Expr, right: Expr)          extends Expr
  case class Divide(left: Expr, right: Expr)            extends Expr
  case class Negative(expr: Expr)                       extends Expr
  def apply(expr: Expr): Expr                 = expr
  def simplifier(expr: Expr): Expr = {
    val simplified = simplify(expr)
    if (simplified == expr) simplified else simplifier(simplified)
  }
  implicit def toExpr(ele: Double): Expr      = Literal(ele)
  implicit def toVariable(name: String): Expr = Variable(name, 1.0)

}

object main extends App {
  import Expr._

  val program: Expr =
    Variable("a", 1.0) + "a" + "a" + "b" + "a" + "a"

  val simplified = simplifier(program)
  println(simplified)
}
```

Comment: Your first problem is to be able to write a parser. Instead of reinventing the wheel in for a seemingly simple yet complex problem like parsing, why not use well researched and developed parsing approaches. I am not very sure but I think a PEG parser might be a good fit for this problem. You can find a PEG parser at - https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2

Comment: @sarveshseri Parsing is not a problem I am able to parser expression properly

Comment: Parsing is never a problem. The problem is alwyas hidden in what your parse (parse tree) output is. You are trying to re-invent the wheel, but your wheel is not even close to being a wheel yet.

Comment: I am doing this problem to understand scala properly that's why I have written my own parser. If you have any better idea please suggest but this how I want to achieve

Comment: Then this is XY problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The simplified string `a * 2 + 1 + a +a` is equivalent to the following expression:

```scala
Add(
  Add(
    Add(
      Multiply(
       Variable("a", 1), 
       Literal(2)
    ), 
    Literal(1)
  ),
  Variable("a",1)
  ), 
Variable("a", 1)
)
```

Obviously, this expression cannot match any of your cases. It's because your expression is formed from left to right.
To overcome this issue I'd suggest making something like `Add(expressions: Seq[Expr])`. Then you will be able to determine identical variables.
I'd also suggest covering the code with unit tests first. It will reduce a lot of time for you.

Comment: Can you explain `Add(expressions: Seq[Expr])` a Little bit more?

Comment: Also, it is not always Add it can be any supported operation

Comment: I mean the following - `a + a + 1` can be `Add(Seq(Variable("a"), Variable("a"), Literal(1)))`. It will allow you change the order of arguments  and simplify.